# requests post - and retry mechanism problem

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have following code in my webscraper:

```
postbody = {'Submit': {}, 'czas_kon2': '', 'czas_pocz2': '', 'num_pacz': '', 'typ': 'wsz'}
post = requests.post(spolka, data=postbody)
data = post.text
```

I am executing it over 400 webpages in a loop, to scrape data using multiprocessing (8 processes).
`data` is supposed to contain whole html page for further xml processing.
But out of 400 pages I get 2 that does not return meaningful content. I suspect it is because of heavy load I create. I tried `time.sleep(1), time.sleep(10)` but no luck here.

How could I ensure that `data` or `post` variable always contain whole page, like for 398 working ones?

I tried simple while loop for retry... but it is far from perfect (I was able to get 1 out of remaining 2 pages) afrer one extra attempt.

```
 while len(data) < 1024:
        postbody = {'Submit': {}, 'czas_kon2': '', 'czas_pocz2': '', 'num_pacz': '', 'typ': 'wsz'}
        post = requests.post(spolka, data=postbody)
        data = post.text
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a request headers.

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0'}
postbody = {'Submit': {}, 'czas_kon2': '', 'czas_pocz2': '', 'num_pacz': '', 'typ': 'wsz'}
post = requests.post(spolka, data=postbody, headers=headers)
```

and more headers example:

```
headers = {
'Accept': 'text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Accept-Language': 'zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
'Host': 'www.google.com',
'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
'Cookies': '',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0'
}
```

Comment: in case of my requests being recognized as robot and banned?

Comment: You should think about why you were identified，I'm pretty sure or your request simulation is not correct, so you can be identified as a robot, it is a very low-level mistakes, you should think about why the browser can get data request, but why can't you, there is only one answer is that you don't sound like a browser requests simulation or, appropriate and request header, this will make you more like a browser